# How do I make Visual Studio Replace default to Current Selection?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2015 I'm having problems with the Ctrl+H shortcut.  In the past if I had text selected and pressed the key combo, the replace box defaults to 'Selection'.  But now it's defaulting to 'Current Document'.  If I change it to 'Selection' it does not retain that setting next time I Ctrl+H

I'm not sure if I've accidentally changed a setting, or if it's always been like this since I installed the 2015 version

Comment: Rather than no keeping 'Selection', it seems to keep 'Selection' as long as you fire `Ctrl+H` with something selected, but resets to 'Current Document' when there's no selection.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can go to `Tools > Options` then in the TreeView, expand the `Environment` node, and choose `Find and Replace` and check the box `Automatically limit search to selection`

Comment: Boom!  What does it say that 6 minutes on SO gives an answer that 10-15 minutes of googling did not.

Comment: Also, it's weird that MSDN calls out the configuration settings for what colors will be used, but makes no mention of the configuration page for the ACTUAL BEHAVIOR of the tool.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139eef4h.aspx

Comment: This used to be the default behavior.  I love how there's another setting I have to remember to dig into when I set up an environment.

Comment: Still has a bug though.  Running VS 2015/Update 1, that checkbox is always cleared when I restart VS, so I have to reset it every morning.

Comment: Me too. Not sure why. I've tried to figure it out and haven't been able to.

Comment: Thank you, this has been bugging me to no end!

Comment: This appears to be the default again as of August 2017 (yeah, I'm making the switch to VS2017...), I definitely noticed it in the past but I went to check this setting and it is already turned on and seems to be working even though I would have sworn it was not working recently.